# function doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, html, audio, local-storage

My `play()` function doesn't get called. I really don't know why.

I have the following code:

```
var mp = document.getElementById("mp3");
   function play() {
   mp.play();
   console.log("hello");
}

function scan() {
  cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
    function(result) {
      if (result.text == "home") {
        var atHomeRepQR = '<div class="container-h"><div class="card"><div class="item item-text-wrap "><i class="icon ion-unlocked"></i> Diese Ansicht ist entsperrt.</div></div><button onclick="play()" class="button button-positive btn">Play</button></div><audio id="mp3"><source src="video/ping.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>';
        save("atHomeSaveQR", atHomeRepQR);
      }
      if (result.text == "street") {
        var atStreetRepQR = '<div class="container-s"><div class="card"><div class="item item-text-wrap "><i class="icon ion-unlocked"></i> Diese Ansicht ist entsperrt.</div></div><button onclick="play()" class="button button-positive btn">Play</button></div><audio id="mp3"><source src="video/ping.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>';
        save("atStreetSaveQR", atStreetRepQR);
      }
      if (result.text == "bern") {
        var atBernRepQR = '<div class="container-b"><div class="card"><div class="item item-text-wrap "><i class="icon ion-unlocked"></i> Diese Ansicht ist entsperrt.</div></div><button onclick="play()" class="button button-positive btn">Play</button></div><audio id="mp3"><source src="video/ping.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>';
        save("atBernSaveQR", atBernRepQR);
      }
      if (result.text == "bahnhof") {
        var atBahnhofRepQR = '<div class="container-ba"><div class="card"><div class="item item-text-wrap "><i class="icon ion-unlocked"></i> Diese Ansicht ist entsperrt.</div></div><button onclick="play()" class="button button-positive btn">Play</button></div><audio id="mp3"><source src="video/ping.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>';
        save("atBahnhofSaveQR", atBahnhofRepQR);
      }
      if (result.text == "atelier") {
        var atAtelierRepQR = '<div class="container-at"><div class="card"><div class="item item-text-wrap "><i class="icon ion-unlocked"></i> Diese Ansicht ist entsperrt.</div></div><button onclick="play()" class="button button-positive btn">Play</button></div><audio id="mp3"><source src="video/ping.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>';
        save("atAtelierSaveQR", atAtelierRepQR);
      }

    },
    function(error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
    }
  );
}
```

The syntax

```
<button onclick="play()" class="button button-positive btn">Play</button></div><audio id="mp3"><source src="video/ping.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

is correct when you ask me.

What's my mistake?

Comment: please check in console, Is there any error? what is mp.play();

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("mp3").play()` - you cannot assign mp=something before something exists.

Comment: Open a browser, load the page containing this code, open the "developper tools" (F12 for Chrome), look at the console tab, and tell us what error you get.

Comment: Can you add a snippet or bin?

Comment: No error, nothing, i updated the code.

Comment: Your `var mp=...` has to be executed after the audio tag has rendered

Comment: @mplungjan so i can place the `mp` in the `play()` function?

Comment: Make sure  function play() { } is written out side the $(document).ready ( function () { });

Comment: change the name of your 'function play()' to something like 'function playit()'. It may work

Comment: Kindly check `var mp = document.getElementById("mp3");` is working or not, I assume you are not getting the element to that variable `mp`

Comment: @sarath you're right! I'm getting `null`back.

Comment: I have tried 'document.getElementById("mp3")`  the same, but can't able to make it right

Comment: @sarath could jquery be a solution?

Comment: @olivier , Jquery May be a solution. I haven't tested.. Please Check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that your `mp` variable is being initialized before `#mp3` is parsed.  You should wrap any static code like that in a `document.ready` block so that its execution is deferred until completion of the page load.

Ideally, this would be achieved using jQuery:

```
var mp;
$(document).ready(function() {
    mp = document.getElementById("mp3");
});
```

In it's absence, this will suffice for most modern browsers (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/800010/1813169)):

```
var mp;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    mp = document.getElementById("mp3");
});
```

Comment: My apologies, I didn't think to expand the comments before answering

Answer (score 0):

I had to place `mp` into the function `play()` like this:

```
   function play() {
   var mp = document.getElementById("mp3");
   mp.play();
}
```

Thanks to mplungjan!

Comment: Or define the mp as a global var and assign it after load

Answer (score 0):

I think, your javascript code is before body tag. Hence in 'mp' element is not getting. So move your javascript code after body tag i.e. after rendering your html.